# Puppeteer - Select value from <select> input element

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

What's the best way to select an option from a select input type of a form in puppeteer?

I've ead that there was a bug in puppeteer and the `.type()` method was not the ideal way to proceed. The select input type in the form have the options value set with a numerical order. Can I simply use this code to set the value?

```js
    page.$x('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/div[10]/select').then( (el) => {
      el.type('1'); // 1 is the first <option value="1">foo</option>
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppeteer has [page.select()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselectselector-values) method, which does exactly that. You just have to give it the value to select. So, assuming you have an  in your :

`page.select('#colors', 'red'); // single selection`

For multi select list you can use:

`page.select('#colors', 'red', 'green', 'blue'); // multiple selections`

Comment: it work also if I select the element using XPath?

Comment: ok. Do you have a quick suggestion also for the date input type?

Comment: Yes. You can use it like that `await page.type("input", dateString)")` to fill date input